# After Insert trigger creating duplicate records

Tags: apex, trigger, tasks, after-trigger

I have a requirement to create a new email_capture__c record when task record is created. Before inserting this record, the requirement is to check if the task description value is matching with existing email__c value in email_capture records. If it is not matching, then create new records.

Here is the logic I have:

```
trigger EmailTrigger on Task (after insert) {
    Email_Capture__c ec = new Email_Capture__c();
        for(Task t:trigger.new){
           for(Email_Capture__c e : [SELECT id, email__c from Email_Capture__c where email__c != null]){
               if(e.email__c != t.description.substringBefore('CC:').substringAfter('To:')){
                   
                   ec.email__c = t.description.substringBefore('CC:').substringAfter('To:');
                   
               }
        }
    }
    insert ec;
}
```

Now, whenever I send an email from a record and new task is getting created, instead of 1 email capture record, I am seeing multiple records getting created.

Can anyone let me know how to overcome this error.

Thanks!

Comment: Based on the requirement, why are you querying for Email_Capture__c records at all? Shouldn't you just be creating a new record for each new task? Is there something I'm misunderstanding or details/specifics you left out?

Comment: @Goncalves, Before inserting, the requirement is to check if the task description value is matching with existing email__c value in email_capture records. If it is not matching, then create new records. I have updated question based on the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I see is that regardless of the amount of records inserted you're only inserting 1 record, which its value email__c will contain only the information from the last Task that fulfills your criteria, with the following edit you should create an Email capture for each tasks created that meets the criteria you mention.

```
trigger EmailTrigger on Task (after insert) {
    List<Email_Capture__c> ecToInsert = new List<Email_Capture__c>();
    Set<String> emails = new Set<String> ();
    for(Task t:trigger.new){
        if(t.description.contains('CC:') && t.description.contains('To:'))
            emails.add(t.description.substringBefore('CC:').substringAfter('To:'));
    }
    for(Email_Capture__c e : [SELECT id, email__c from Email_Capture__c where email__c IN: emails]){
        emails.remove(e.email__c);
    }
    for(String email : emails){
        Email_Capture__c ec = new Email_Capture__c();
        ec.email__c = email;
        ecToInsert.add(ec)
            }
    insert ecToInsert;
}
```

PD: I recommend that you check the usage of Apex trigger Handler, to follow best practices.  You can find plenty information by just searching

> apex trigger handler

Example:
https://www.forcetalks.com/blog/salesforce-apex-trigger-handler-the-developer-guide/

Comment: worth it to point out naming convention (EmailTrigger on a Task object, what happens when you have a different Task-related requirement?) and that there are multiple types of Tasks a user could be creating out of your control - (ex. a call, random to-do, etc) so there should probably be a check it's a type of task you want.

Comment: @aAlexander, even though there is a matching email_capture__c record with matching email__c value, another new record is getting created. Could you please suggest any update here?

Comment: @Kris Yes, I was just trying to answer without having him to refactor too much or adding to much filters that obviously accordingly to Best practices would be in order. But Since I don't know much about how they're using their org I  prefer to not add that much logic.

Comment: @SFDCUser I'm not aware of any other processes you might have in your org that might be interfering, but this code should be only inserting record if another record with same email doesn't exists.